# juntar tabelas em sql sem primary keys ou foreign keys comuns às 2 tabelas

Tags: sql

Tenho que fazer uma pesquisa em SQL em varias tabelas.

Preciso relacionar as duas através de um "id" comum porém não sei como pois não possuo declarado primary keys nem foreign keys.

Segue trecho de código:

```
SELECT a.iban, TO_CHAR(date_, 'month ,yyyy-dd') AS "Opening date", o.client_id AS "Client NR.", op.status
FROM operation o JOIN open_operation op ON o.id_op = op.id
                 JOIN account a ON o.account_id = a.id   
                 JOIN client c ON o.client_id = c.id
```

Segue informação que precisa constar na query anterior:

```
SELECT y.name 
FROM agency y JOIN account a ON y.id = a.agency_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mesmo que não exista as chaves declaradas, pelo que você descreveu esses campos se relacionam da seguinte forma:

```
agency.id = account.agency_id
```

Portanto um simples `JOIN` resolveria, depende do resultado que você deseja um subselect pode ser necessário.

```
SELECT a.iban
   , TO_CHAR(date_, 'month ,yyyy-dd') AS "Opening date"
   , o.client_id AS "Client NR.", op.status
   , y.name
FROM operation o 
JOIN open_operation op 
   ON o.id_op = op.id
JOIN account a 
   ON o.account_id = a.id   
JOIN client c 
   ON o.client_id = c.id 
JOIN agency y
   ON y.id = a.agency_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A definição de primary key e de foreign key não sãe necessárias. São uma definição que limita certas acções do sistema.

**Embora não seja aconselhado**, tecnicamente, podes ter uma base de dados sem nenhuma chave definida.

Podes, por exemplo, estar a definir as relações apenas nas queries. è uma questão de abordagem.

por exemplo, o atributo X pode representar uma relação para 2 ou mais tabelas, embora seja pouco usado, ou mesmo para diferentes atributos da mesma tabela em diferentes situações.

è tudo uma questão de abordagem.